# Ubuntu Installation - Use As, Mount Point, and Device for boot loader installation selections

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mountpoint

I am currently installing Ubuntu Desktop on my Windows 11 machine (dual-boot, not replacing Windows OS). I partitioned my disk in half so that half of it is for my Windows OS and the other half is free space which I can use now for Ubuntu. I am following [a YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXxTxBPKecQ&t=313s)
and am at the part where I choose my "Use as:", "mount point", and "Device for boat loader installation.

For "Use as", there are 13 options: Ext4 journaling file system, Ext3 journaling file system, Ext2 file system, btrfs journaling file system, JFS journaling file system, XFS journaling file system, FAT16 file system, FAT32 file system, swap area, Reserved BIOS boot area, EFI System Partition, physical volume for encryption, and do not use partition.

For "mount point" there are 9 options: /, /boot, /home, /tmp, /usr, /var, /srv, /opt, and /usr/local.

For Device for boot loader installation there are 7 options: /dev/sda ATA ST500LM034-2GH17, /dev/sda1 Windows Boot Manager, /dev/sda3, /dev/sda5, /dev/sda4, /dev/sdb General UDisk, and /dev/sdb4.

They can all be seen in the pictures below.

- Use As: [image]
- Mount Point: [image]
- Device for boot loader installation: [image]

The guy in the video selected Ext4 journaling file system for "Use as" which was the default. For "mount point" there was no default but he chose /. For "Device for boot loader installation" the default was /dev/sda ATA ST500LM034-2GH17 but he chose /dev/sda1 Windows Boot Manager. Before I go ahead and install, I would like to get some second opinions to confirm that these are what I should select, and if not, which other ones I should use. The video does not talk about the different options. I am brand new to using Ubuntu and don't know what I'm doing in regards to the installation process.

This is the youtube tutorial:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use As, Mount Point, and Device for Boot Loader Installation

For your case

- Use As: **Ext4 journaling file system**
- Mount Point: **/**
- Device for Boot Loader Installation: **/dev/sda ATA ST500LM034-2GH17**

Comment: If post a variation of this answer to update the currently obsolete answers to [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/) I will upvote both answers.  Please use a big heading font like you did on this answer, so new Ask Ubuntu users can see it. Maybe even include a screenshot for the visually impaired. Please ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) when it's done.

Comment: @Karel which answer on that page are you talking about? There are thirteen. I do not see a method that includes an EFI partition, except LiveWireBT's , but people nowadays do not tend to use /home partitions. I think this OP will find the above answer more tailored to their needs than working through all the answers on your link. If I can find the time I will try to take you up on your offer, but I have paying work at present. In the meantime, I would suggest LiveWireBT's answer.

Comment: My biggest complaint is that the top upvoted answers always say to create a swap partition instead of a swap file, and I want something more modern. Including information about an EFI partition would certainly be useful.

Comment: Ubuntu automatically mounts the ESP - efi system partition on first drive. If one does not exist on empty drive it will create one. If one does not exist and installing to another drive it fails. Ubuntu changed to swap file of 2GB. New systems that can use Ubuntu have enough RAM they will rarely if ever use swap. Some that use servers still like to have a 4GB swap partition. New users do not really need separate /home, and now with snaps / needs to be a lot larger than older suggestions. I have no snaps and with Kubuntu use 16GB in / with all data in a data partition.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I did install it last night. I ended up using /dev/sda1 Windows Boot Manager for Device for boot loader installation. Everything seems to be ok. When I start up my device, a menu comes up and I can select Ubuntu or Windows. Out of curiousity, what's the difference between /dev/sda1 Windows Boot Manager and the option you suggested?

Comment: @Ben: All the instructions for using the "Something else" method that I have seen suggest using the disk  /dev/sdx for boot loader installation not the partition /dev/sdxy. In my experiments using a partition works but I am not sure if that allows booting both Legacy and UEFI.  If you look at the answers on karel's link, they are all installing the boot loader to /dev/sda. Back in the old days, there was no EFI partition.